# Get the index numbers of mismatching column values between to dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have two similar dataframes like this

Dataframe 1:

```
ID        classification
1         MISS
2         MISS
3         CORRECT
4         MISS
5         CORRECT
```

Dataframe 2:

```
ID        classification
1         CORRECT
2         CORRECT
3         MISS
4         MISS
5         CORRECT
```

I would like get the index numbers for each time there is a mismatch between values in the classification column between dataset 1 and dataset 2. The datasets are of similar length and the remaining columns are also equal to each other.

Comment: `ID` is `print (df1.index)` or column `df1['ID']` ?

Comment: ```ID``` is ```df1['ID']```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because same number of rows and same indices you can compare `classification` between both DataFrames for not equal by [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) and filter values in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
#ID is index
df1.index[df1['classification'].ne(df2['classification'])]
```

Or if `ID` in column:

```
df1.loc[df1['classification'].ne(df2['classification']), 'ID']
```

If not same number of rows use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html), here `ID` is column:

```
s = df2.set_index('ID')['classification']
df1.loc[df1['classification'].ne(df1['ID'].map(s)), 'ID']
```